# How to test successful token claim with jwt

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-testing, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm using django rest simple jwt and I wanted to test a simple login and check the response data for the token and other custom data.

So I tried with the APITestCase to create an user and then try a login with the same credentials.

The results is a 401 instead a 200 with a token in response data.

Here is my test case simplified:

```py
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

# Create your tests here.
User = get_user_model()

class UserAuthTestCase(APITestCase):
    username = "someuser"
    password = "1234pass"


    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create(
            username=self.username,
            password=self.password
        )

    def test_successful_login_gives_200(self):
        response = self.client.post(
            '/auth/token/',
            {
                'username': self.username,
                'password': self.password
            },
            format='json'
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

The the rest framework configuration is set to use the simplejwt authentication only.

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the `User` with `User.objects.create` you are setting the password without *hashing* so when you later try to authenticate the user you end up comparing the hashed password value withe the raw unhashed password in the database. Use `User.objects.create_user` which handles hashing by calling `set_password` internally.

Comment: Missed that part, I never tested auth before and DRF testing page didn't cover this part. In case somebody got here I drop the link to django docs page about it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/